# Webview não lê com alguns códigos javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview

Estou com um problema ao utilizar o webview do Swift, notei que alguns códigos javascript que estão dentro da página carregada não rodam. Exemplo:

onclick="functionMuitoLegal()"

Porém se faço a mesma coisa usando react na página a ser carregada, o onclick funciona normalmente dentro do webview:

onclick={functionMuitoLegal}

Alguém já enfrentou este problema ? Sabe o motivo disso ocorrer para que eu possa contorná-lo ?

A url carrega normalmente e os prints desse código abaixo estão sendo exibidos no console do xcode:

```
override func loadView() {
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.preferences = preferences

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    print("carrega delegate ")
    view = webView
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  print("carregou página")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema lendo o JS que a página rodava, o onclick estava funcionando, o propósito dele era rodar uma função JS e submeter um form, na submissão tinha um redirect vindo de header que usava http, como iOS só aceita https dava impressão que nada acontecia.

Deixar essa resposta aqui para se tiver mais alguém com a mesma falta de atenção que eu.